# How to use column name from an outer clause in an inner clause?

Tags: sql

How can I use the value from an outer clause inside an inner clause using nested SELECT statements?   Eg:

```
SELECT cost AS c, quantity, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM accounts WHERE cost = c) 
FROM accounts
```

Can `c` be referenced in the inner SELECT clause as attempted above?

Comment: This works fine in MySQL. What are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the outer table (eg. `FROM accounts AS a`). Then you can simply do `a.cost` in the inner subquery.

EDIT. That being said, there's a better way to write this query without a sub-query for each row:

```
SELECT a.cost, a.quantity, COUNT(b.id) AS count
FROM accounts AS a LEFT JOIN accounts AS b ON b.cost = a.cost
```

Comment: how does the inner clause know whether it is the outer or inner version of accounts?

Comment: ah, sorry, should alias the outer table as something else and use the alias. i'll edit the answer

Comment: What SQL are you using?  I can't seem to alias tables like that. I can only do: accounts a

Comment: Well, I'm mostly familiar with MySQL, but it's all the same; `accounts a` and `accounts AS a` does the same thing.